# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox select element with no name

Tags: perl, www-mechanize-firefox

how to select option element from select only with class using [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox).

For example:

```
<select class="alabala">
<option value="a1">a1</option>
<option value="a2">a2</option>
<option value="a3">a3</option>
<option value="a4">a4</option>
<option value="a5">a5</option>
<option value="a6">a6</option>
</select>
```

How to select a2?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far to try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would set any other value in the form:

```
$mech->field(".alabala", "a2");
```